# Print a Text File

Tags: c#, printing, printf

I am trying to print a text file while executing this code, it's printing a empty document.
There is no contents inside the generated pdf (Default printer is pdf995 or adobe pdf).It would be helpful if someone can help me for this.

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace Advanced.PDF.Extended
{
    public class PrintTxtFile : CodeActivity
    {
        [Category("Input")]
        [Description(@" For Ex : C:\Users\userid\Desktop\Input\exam.txt")]
        [DisplayName("Input File Name")]
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> SourceFile { get; set; }

        [Category("Input")]
        [DisplayName("Print in Landscape")]
        public bool Landscape { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var fileName = SourceFile.Get(context);
            try
            {
                var pd = new PrintDocument
                {
                    DocumentName = fileName,
                    DefaultPageSettings =
                    {
                        Landscape = this.Landscape
                    }
                };
                pd.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            finally { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` when the code is clearly not Javascript?

Comment: Dont know how it came

Comment: Sorry, Rajan, I forgot to say I was specifically asking @TCouch, who was the one who added the tag. But you should be able to correct it with an edit of your own. What language is it? C#?

Comment: Yes it's an C# Language